Can I run functions before render in Next server components?
In an async server component, if I run some function on data used in the render, does it get computed before the render happens? Do I need to set up this function return as a promise? Do I need to create a client sub-component that uses classic useState and useEffect to ensure these functions are run on the data before the render? Or is this fine because it is waiting for the for the function to run before rendering?
Example:
export default async function Home() {

  const posts = await db.post.findMany();

  const doSomeStuffToPosts = (posts) => { 
    bla bla bla;
    return someNewData;
  };

  const newPostsData = doSomeStuffToPosts(posts);

  return (
   {newPostsData.map((newPost) => <IndividualPostData newPost={newPost} />
  );
}


im not sure i correctly got your question but if you are asking that is const posts = await db.post.findMany(); finish work before rendering then answer is yes, rendering will be after other stuff what you are writing before.

@IgorZinchenko I'm asking if doSomeStuffToPosts is guaranteed to complete before the render happens. In normal React I would run doSomeStuffToPosts in a useEffect and set the state from there. So it seems weird to run functions like doSomeStuffToPosts outside of lifecycle.

yes, doSomeStuffToPosts do transformation before render.
